# If statement that only satisfies when both conditions are met - Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out the issue with this code. I'm coding in python. I want my condition to fail only when both statements are inside an array. Otherwise, I'm looking for this code to pass and print "Enter".

```
edge1 = []
edge2 = []
edge1.append("hello")
edge2.append("world")

if ("hello" not in edge1 and "bye" not in edge2):
    print("entered")
```

Expected output: "entered"

Comment: Your code works fine. What is the problem?

Comment: Swap the `and` for an `or`.

Comment: `"hello"` is in `edge`, why would you expect it to print "entered` ?

Comment: if not ("hello" in edge1 and "bye"  in edge2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said, "I want my condition to fail only when both statements are inside an array."

Your 'if' condition should be like following

```
if (not ( "hello" in edge1 and "bye" in edge2)):
    print("entered")
```

i.e. 'not' should be applied to the final outcome